# Next step prediction function in R

Tags: r, predict

Below is a portion of my code. The data frame ends at 139, I'm trying to predict the 140<sup>th</sup> `Y` value using my linear regression, but it does not generate anything.

```
glreg3 <- lm(Y ~ Ypast1+Ypast2+Ypast3+Ypast4+Ypast12+Ypast13+summer+spring+fall+winter+t, data=YX2)

tf <- data.frame(t=140)

predict(glreg3, newdata=YX2$tf, interval="prediction", level=.95)
```

Comment: You created `tf` as a new object instead of as another row in your data for prediction? What do you see when you print `tf`, or `YX2$tf`? I don't think you get a result because there are no predictor variables for the model to work on...

Comment: tf gives me 140. I need to figure out what my glreg3 gives me in the next step, which is at time=140. I can't seem to use the predict function...